# Why am I getting 239 VAC between GND and line when the device is turned off?

Tags: safety

I noticed a weird thing that I don't understand.

I'm working on an electronics project which has inside of it a 230 VAC (I'm in Europe) to 12 VDC transformer.

For the convenience, the project is plugged to the Eaton ePDU G3, which is a sort of a very smart network-controlled power strip which, among others, allows to power each socket on and off. The PDU is connected in turn to the UPS, that is, a unit with a battery inside which keeps powering the appliances in a case of an outage. Finally, the UPS itself is plugged into a surge suppressor. Everything is grounded properly.

When the device is powered on, everything works as expected. When I measure the difference between the two wires, this is what I get:

- GND ↔ Line: 239 V
- Neutral ↔ Line: 239 V
- GND ↔ Neutral: 1 V

However, when I turn the device off through the PDU, I get:

- **GND ↔ Line: 239 V**
- Neutral ↔ Line: grows from 4 V to 36 V for something like thirty seconds, then drops to zero, grows again, etc.
- GND ↔ Neutral: decreases from 236 to 215 V for something like thirty seconds, then goes back to 236 V and starts decreasing again.

The measurements are taken with an inexpensive multimeter, which may explain why adding the values from the last two rows doesn't always equal 239 V. I don't have an oscillograph, so I can't see the exact pattern.

I imagined that the mechanical relay which turns the appliance on and off in the PDU is acting on the Line, breaking the connection when the socket is turned off. In practice, the relay acts on the Neutral instead. This creates an electric shock hazard: it looks like the appliance is powered down, but there is still a 239 V differential between some of the wires inside.

What could be the reason for a PDU to do it this way? Am I missing something?

Comment: Triac leakage?...  any diagrams?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: not sure triacs are involved. In all cases, when the socket is turned on and off, there is a recognizable click of a mechanical relay.

Comment: It is possible that something is wired "backward", so that line and neutral are reversed. Or it is possible that the SPDT actually does work on the Neutral instead of Line. Is there a way to reverse the polarity with the plug? If so, take measurements with polarity reversed.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy: if they were reversed, wouldn't it lead to the reading at 239 V between ground and neutral when the appliance is turned on?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Socket on PDU disconnected by switching neutral. In that case you have full line voltage on neutral trough load. It is dangerous situation because standart protection will not work properly. In North America electrical code pretty straight about neutral. It should not be disconnected. Switch wires connection to main source. You can distinguish neutral by connection to ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power strip probably uses a TRIAC or other solid state switch device to turn the AC on and off at the outlets.  As with all electronic components, there is leakage current through the device when it is "off".  Not enough to hurt someone, but enough to get the attention of a meter with a megohm or multi-megohm input impedance.  Attach a small load, such as an incandescent night-light bulb, across the meter input and the reading should drop to near zero.

OK, I wrote that before I caught the significance of the second part of your post.  It still applies to why you get a voltage reading when things should be off, but not to why the main disconnect is in the Neutral rather than the Line.  For that I have no answer except poor manufacturing oversight - it could be a wiring error.  The next step is that the power strip is designed that way, and that is bad.  Someone around here who knows more about European wiring practices might be able to add more.

Comment: This would explain the fluctuation between 4 and 36 V, but my question was primary about the 239 V between ground and line (and nearly 239 V between ground and neutral). Additionally, the PDU makes a distinct click sound of a mechanical relay when an appliance is switched on and off, which, I suppose, shouldn't leak.

Answer (score 3):

The PDU opens the neutral line so it has to be reversed but then we have to restore overall connection which is already straight

So for instance flip both PDU input plug (PDU-UPS) and load input plug (load-PDU)

Answer (score 1):

Possible scenario: If the neutral is switched, and in the power supply there is an EMC capacitor between ground and L, the EMC capacitor leakage may be charging the power supply capacitors slowly. Once the minimum operating voltage of the power supply circuit is reached, the supply springs into action and discharges its input capacitors. Rinse and repeat. Hence the oscillating 4-36V. Establishing the actual current paths taken is left as an exercise for the reader.